# State Machines, Sub-Classes, and Function Pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers, state-machine, subclass

I'm having trouble implementing a state machine for class. I keep getting the errors:

```
state.cpp:5: error: have0 was not declared in this scope 
state.cpp:10: error: redefinition of State* Have0State::process(std::string)
state.h:18: error: virtual State* Have0State::process(std::string) previously defined here
```

I'm trying to get the Have0State to work before I continue onto the rest of the machine, hence the sparse code.

state.h:

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H

#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>


class State{
    public:
        State(){};
        virtual State* process(std::string input) = 0;


};
class Have0State: public State {
    public:
        Have0State():State(){};
        virtual State* process(std::string input);
}have0;
#endif
```

state.cpp:

```
#include "state.h"

using namespace std;
State *currentState = &have0;

State* Have0State::process(string input){
    if(input == "quarter"){
        cout << "cool" << endl;
    }
    return &have0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string input;
    //get input
    cin >> input;
    while (input != "exit") {
        currentState = currentState->process(input);
        //get input
        cin >> input;

    }
    return 0;
};
```

I've tried defining the process function as `Have0State::State::process(string input)` but that didn't work either. Any clarification on how function pointers are supposed to work, especially in the context of subclass member functions, I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: Also, what exactly is the `have0` declaration at the end of the `Have0State` class declaration in the state.h file? It doesn't have an explicitly stated type; is it implied that it is of type Have0State??

Comment: the have0 definition seems to be similar to how struct variables were sometimes defined in C. Very rare and will cause you issues later (variables in headers always do), so you should move it elsewhere.

Comment: is there a `{}` at the end of the definition in `state.h`? Else refactor out `have0` and see if it helps.

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us exactly the same code that generated the error? I just pasted the code (both the contents of the header and the contents of the cpp file below the header, omitting `#ifndef` guards) into an online compiler and it compiled fine.

Comment: @KarthikT there is not. I don't see a corresponding opening bracket so I assumed that semi-colon was all it needed

Comment: @MaciejHehl It is, just checked again...

Comment: you are redefining the virtual process in Have0State instead of just implementing it, which lead to the pure virtual from State to be ignored and Have0State having 2 declaration for the same process function

Comment: I made one more test. I pasted your code into appropriate files in a new VS 2012 Express C++ project. Everything compiled fine

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any function pointers in your example.  Also, like Marciej, I am able to compile (and run) this code.

But, since you asked, the 'have0' declaration simply declares an instance of the class.  A class definition can be followed by 0 or more of these declarations (as well as initializers):

```
class Thing {...} one, another, many[3] = { Thing(1), Thing(2), Thing(3) };
```

the same as for any other type:

```
int counter = 0, flag = 0x80, limit = 500;
```

The possibility of this optional declarator list is why class, struct, union, and enum definitions must be followed with a semi-colon (to terminate the list).

But, as Karthik said, defining a variable in a header will cause "duplicate definition" errors at link time, if the header is included in more than one .cpp file.  IMO it's fine though to use this technique to define and declare private objects in a .cpp file (rather than a .h file).